# Joomla css disabling

Tags: css, joomla, joomla2.5

So I got image gallery based on css (no javascript) and I'd like to place it into the Joomla's article. Problem is, even I change id's and class's of every single tag in the gallery (and also in it's three css files) Joomla is still messing around with the styling of the gallery. It could be caused by the fact that whole article is in some s and it has its own styling which breaks gallery's styling. Is there any way I could disable tamplate's css in the part of an article or in whole article and load my own css for the current article? I would welcome any solution which could stop Joomla messing around with my gallery.

Comment: You didn't get it. I already have an gallery and also Joomla webpage. My problem is Joomla is breaking my gallery's styling with it's own css. So I have to reset the css somehow. By the way
`div.reset, div.reset *
{
    // styling
}`
doesn't work :/

Comment: it means you want to customise css

Comment: You should provide a link to your site and to the image gallery. We cant really suggest anything without looking at anything ;)

Comment: Sorry I'm working on localhost :/

Comment: try important keyword

Answer (score 0):

So I've figured this out!

Putting into the gallery another `<div id="resetcss">` and in the tamplate's css file setting proper style for necessary tags such a `<a>, <img>, <div>, <h1> ...` solved my problem.

Or also `#resetcss *{}` filled with some basics such a `margin:0, padding:0, font-size:100%, ...` is great solution.

Hope this will help somebody.

/edit: it's **important** to put `<div id="resetcss">` in the right place (between another divs) into gallery (or any other element) to avoid some inconveniences as wrong align or so.